# Plotting a frequency function

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have a list of numbers and I want to plot the fraction of numbers >= k against k which will naturally be a decreasing curve. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

E.g.:

```
test = RandomInteger[100, 100];

ListLinePlot[With[{r = Reverse@Sort@Tally[test]}, 
  Transpose[{Reverse@r[[All, 1]], Reverse@Accumulate@r[[All, 2]]}]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this?

```
list = RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[100, 0.1], {10000}];
```

You can use `list` to construct an [`EmpiricalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html), and then use `DiscretePlot` (if the list is all integers) or `Plot` (if it's reals) to plot the complement of its [`CDF`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CDF.html).

```
dist = EmpiricalDistribution[list];

DiscretePlot[1 - CDF[dist, x], {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot of CDF's complement]

Answer (score 2):

Few more alternatives/variations:

```
data = RandomReal[50, 100];
```

1. `HistogramList` with height spec `"SF"`:

   `ListLinePlot[#, PlotRange -> {{0, 60}, Automatic}]&@Thread@PadRight@HistogramList[data, 1000, "SF"]`
2. `SurvivalFunction` and `EmpiricialDistribution`

   `Plot[SurvivalFunction[EmpiricalDistribution[data], x], {x, 0, 60}, Exclusions -> None]`
3. Plain old `Histogram` with height spec `"SF"`

   `Histogram[data, 1000, "SF", PlotRange -> {{0, 60}, Automatic}];`

[image]